# FrameLayout wrap_content in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-framelayout

My `FrameLayout` inside a `CoordinatorLayout` doesn't want to be `wrap_content`. When I select `wrap_content` with the ui tool it does not set it to `wrap_content` but set a defined height of **48dp**.

I also tried to set it directly in the xml file and it works... Until I reopen the file. I suppose AS's editor is doing some work and reset its height to **48dp**.

This is how my layout looks like :

```
<layout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.mydomain.relationViewModel" />

    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"

            android:visibility="@{viewModel.isLoading() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.isLoading() ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE}">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/hint"
                tools:text="Relation"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:text="@string/relationship_spinner_hint"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/hint"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

                app:setOnItemSelectedListener="@{viewModel.relationshipsListener}"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:id="@+id/search_fragment_container"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_patient_title">

            </FrameLayout>

            <Button
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                style="@style/buttonStyle"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_fragment_container" />

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/search_patient"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/search_patient_title"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                tools:text="Recherche du patient"
                style="@style/myTitle" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

And here is a screenshot of my blueprint (where the selected layout is the `FrameLayout`):

[image: Blueprint]

Thank's for any further help !

**EDIT**
Got the same issue with CardView (seems legit since it's a FrameLayout child).

Comment: That's a bug -- can you file this on code.google.com with your example? thanks!

Comment: Done. You can follow it with this link : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/tQ2cBT0ujKI

Comment: Thanks! the bug is similar to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225912 so we'll track this one.

Comment: I have a similar issue placing a Spinner in a Constraint Layout. Setting match_parent and/or wrap_content is hard wiring layout_width to 48dp. I have to say that every time I've come back to trying ConstraintLayout after a frustrating episode I've hit yet another "issue".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this [Google bug ticket](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225912) is saying :

> Fixed in master.
>
> Released with Android Studio 2.3 beta 1